# ROS Tutorial clarification

Tags: catkin, tutorial, catkin-package, genmsg, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the (catkin) tutorials to get started with ROS, and I run into the following.

In CreatingMsgAndSrv tutorial it says I should add this to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation)
```

But in the next tutorial (WritingPublisherSubscriber) it says I should have this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)
```

Another inconsistency I found:

> Also make sure you export the message runtime dependency.

```
catkin_package( ... CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ... )
```

while on the next page:

```
catkin_package()
```

So, the question is, which one of these should I use? Does it matter? What's the difference?

Thanks

---

The links for pages mentioned:

ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv
ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58367/ros-tutorial-clarification/) by [Gabor Juhasz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4450/gabor-juhasz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you put in your CMakeLists.txt depends on what you are doing in your package.  If you are just writing a simple node you don't need to export CATKIN_DEPENDS and you don't need to depends on message_generation.

There's a good summary of what CATKIN_DEPENDS is for in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/58498/what-is-the-purpose-of-catkin_depends/)

Whereas if you are creating messages like the first tutorial you do need to do those things so the the messages can be generated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1